# Complex variable trigonometric identity (arctan).

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Under the hypothesis that: 
$$\log \left( z\right) =a+ib $$
And: 
$$z\log \left( z\right) =p+iq $$
Show that: 
$$\arctan \left( \dfrac {p}{q}\right) =\arctan \left( \dfrac {a}{b} \right )-b$$

Comment: What branch of $\log$ are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\tag{0}z=\dfrac{z log(z)}{log(z)}=\dfrac{p+iq}{a+ib}=\dfrac{(p+iq)(a-ib)}{a^2+b^2}=\dfrac{(ap+bq)+i(aq - bp)}{a^2+b^2}$$

Let $$\tag{1}z=c+id.$$

The quotient $\dfrac{\Im(z)}{\Re(z)}$ can be written in two ways, either by using (0) or (1):

$$\tag{2}\dfrac{d}{c}=\dfrac{aq-bp}{ap+bq}=\dfrac{\frac{a}{b}-\frac{p}{q}}{1+\frac{a}{b}\frac{p}{q}}$$

Setting $$\tag{3}\cases{\tan(\alpha)=\frac{a}{b}\\ \tan(\beta)=\frac{p}{q}\\ \tan(\gamma)=\frac{d}{c}}$$

we can write (2) under the form:

$$\tan(\gamma)=\dfrac{\tan(\alpha)-\tan(\beta)}{1+\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}$$

i.e., $$\tag{4}\tan(\gamma)=\tan(\alpha-\beta) \ \  \Longleftrightarrow \gamma=\alpha-\beta \ \ (mod \ \pi)$$

The last expression in (4) can be written, using (3), into the following way:

$$\tag{5}\gamma=\arctan(\frac{a}{b})-\arctan(\frac{p}{q})$$

It is clear that it remains to show that

$\tag{6}\gamma=b$

This comes from the fact (see def. (1)), that, calling $r$ the modulus of $z$:

$$\log(z)=a+ib=\log(c+id)=\log( re^{i \ arctan(d/c)})=\log( re^{i\gamma})=\log(\sqrt{c^2+d^2}e^{i\gamma})$$

which becomes:

$$a+ib=\frac{1}{2}\ln(c^2+d^2)+i\gamma$$

(6) is then obtained by identifying the imaginary parts.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, it's not technically true. Take $z = e^{-1}\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then $\log z = -1 + i\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k\right)$ for some integer $k$ (since the branch wasn't specified, this is the best we can say.) If we take $k=0$, then $\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = \arctan\left(-\frac{1}{\pi/4}\right)<\arctan(-1) = -\frac{\pi}{4}$, and so $\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) - b < -\frac{\pi}{2}$, but the range of $\arctan$ is $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, so we cannot have $\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)-b = \arctan\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$. If we take $k\ne 0$, then $b = \frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k$ and hence $-b\not\in(-\pi,\pi)$, but $\arctan\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\in(-\pi,\pi)$ again due to the range of $\arctan$, so we cannot have $\arctan\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = -b$.

Nonetheless, the statement is true modulo $\pi$, and I will show that below.

---

Since $\log(z) = a+ib$, we have $z = e^a(\cos b+i\sin b)$, and hence
$$z\log(z) = e^a(\cos b + i\sin b)(a+ib) = e^a(a\cos b - b\sin b + i(a\sin b + b\cos b)).$$
It follows that $p = e^a(a\cos b - b\sin b)$ and $q = e^a(a\sin b + b\cos b)$. If we let $a = r\sin\theta$ and $b = r\cos\theta$, we then have
$$p = e^a(r\sin\theta\cos b - r\cos\theta\sin b) = e^ar\sin(\theta-b)$$
and
$$q = e^a(r\sin\theta\sin b + r\cos\theta\cos b) = e^ar\cos(\theta-b)$$
thus yielding
$$\frac{p}{q} = \tan(\theta-b)\implies\arctan\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) \equiv \theta - b\mod \pi.$$
By noticing that $\tan\theta = \frac{a}{b}$, we have that 
$$\theta\equiv \arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\mod\pi,$$
thus yielding our conclusion.